# Is there a way to reuse a regex pattern as both a patternProperties key and string type pattern in a json schema?

Tags: jsonschema

For example, in the [GBFS](https://github.com/NABSA/gbfs) project, top level keys in the `gbfs.json['properties']['data']` object are [described as](https://github.com/NABSA/gbfs/blob/master/gbfs.md#gbfsjson):

> language: The language that will be used throughout the rest of the files. It MUST match the value in the system_information.json file.

This is enforced by a [`patternProperties` definition in the `gbfs.json` schema](https://github.com/MobilityData/gbfs-json-schema/blob/0e3651f2c03f41c2dc8cb2852a020e37f90f42d5/gbfs.json#L31). But as described by the explanation of the field, this property should match a [string property with the same regex pattern in `system_information.json`](https://github.com/MobilityData/gbfs-json-schema/blob/0e3651f2c03f41c2dc8cb2852a020e37f90f42d5/system_information.json#L39).

Would there be a way to define this regex pattern once and use it both as a `patternProperties` key and string type pattern for the `language` field?

Answer (score 0):

Not in JSON Schema syntax itself, but you could go up one level and generate your schema programmatically, say with a template that used a placeholder variable for that regex. You could then use the template to regenerate the schema whenever it changed -- for example, if your schema is normally kept in git, then you could use a git commit hook to update the regex in all the places it is used. Or if you deploy your schema with ansible, you can generate the file with a template there too.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, not with JSON Schema itself.

The common approach to solving this problem is to use Jsonnet, which is a templating language for JSON.

https://jsonnet.org

Having not used it myself, I have no opinions on it, beyond I've seen it used effectively in large scale projects in the course of researching JSON Schema use cases.